# WebSocket connection

Tags: php, сервер, сокет, websocket

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь настроить `websocket`, а у меня постоянно выдает ошибку.
Порт существует, я могу к нему подключится через `php`, а если это делать из `js` фала постоянно выскакивает ошибка.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Я так понимаю что-то блокирует, вопрос только вот что?
В фаервол добавлял этот порт, не помогло.

Сервер на `VestaCp` на локалке такой-же сервер только без весты и все работает, я так понимаю что скорее всего дело в `nginx` так как на локалке его нет и все прекрасно работает.

Помогите пожалуйста, спасибо!

Comment: Пользуйтесь Socket.io.

Тут походу есть ответ на ваш вопрос 
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/26627052/6120970

Comment: порт 8000 доступен из вне на серваке?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно настроить фаервол VestaCP - то есть открыть соответствующий порт в её настройках. По умолчанию VestaCP закрывает все ненужные порты на сервере. Еще порт открыть можно вручную с помощью `iptables`

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables-save
```

Но лучше всё же воспользоваться интерфейсом VestaCP, в котором можно открыть необходимый порт. Сделать это можно в меню "Firewall", вот пример данной страницы[image: Пример страницы фаервола]

Comment: можно немножко поподробнее как добавить в iptables?

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает=(